# Connecting and disconnecting a modem to get a new ip

Tags: usb-modem, modem

Can somebody help with a script which can disconnect and reconnect the  modem to get a new IP.
Ubuntu 14.04
--Thanks

Comment: I take it you are using a broadband USB modem dongle. In which case the IP is set by your Internet Service Provider (ISP). You would have to contact them for an IP change.

Comment: @DanJohansen Often ISP assign a new IP after disconnect / reconnect

Comment: @Jan perhaps. But that depends solely on the ISP in question. :)

Comment: with windows using the bat script i was getting the different ip, but in ubuntu the ip i am getting is the same.The modem is same.Are there any workarounds to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using NetworkManager:

Deactivate : `nmcli con down id "connection name"`
Re-activate : `nmcli con up id "connection name"`

Comment: i want a script... something like wdial command as i will not be running it manually.... i need to run it like a proram may be every 1 hr to reset my ip

Comment: Just add a shebang at the top and voilà, you have a script file :-) Show some research effort!

Comment: Thanx for the reply,,,now its working

Comment: getting a new IP every hour seems shady to me.... ;)